# Comparing two functions based on Asymptotic notations

Tags: function, big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

```
f(n)= 1 + 2 + 3 + · · + n      
 g(n) = 3(n^2) + nlogn
```

**Determining f = O(g) or
f = Ω(g) or f = Θ(g)**

.As per my effort and understanding one guess It might be **f=O(g)** as g(n) has a n^2 power which grows faster than n .

**Another way** : if divided both by n , f(n) will have a constant 1 and g(n) : nlogn which grows faster than constant 1 . so , f=O(g) .
Is that a correct answer?

---

What actually is scaling property of Big-O ?
How to prove : For any constant c > 0, **cf(n) is O(f(n))**.

Understanding so far :
**cf(n) < (c + k)f(n) holds for all n > 0 and k > 0.**

i. Constant factors are ignored.

ii. Only the powers and functions of n should be exploited
It is this ignoring of constant factors that motivates for such a
notation. Which proves f is O(f).

Is this explanation enough to prove that scaling property of Big-O ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f(n)=O(g(n)) if there is a positive constant c such as.
|f(n)| <= c*|g(n)| for all n>=n(initial)

and since f(n)=(n(n-1))/2 ----> (n^2)

n^2<= n^2 + nlogn (ignore the constants), for all n>=1 then yes your answer is right.